# R Avoid rowwise() and looking for faster alternative

Tags: r, rowwise

I want to merge two vectors into one dataset and integrate it with the function `mutate` as 5 new columns into the already existing dataset.
Here is my example code:

```
vector1<-list(c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search"),c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search"),c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search"))
vector2<-list(c(1,2,6,3,4),c(3,7,9,2,4),c(5,2,8,4,0))

tibble(vector1=vector1,
       vector2=vector2)%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(vector2|> set_names(vector1)|> as.list()|> data.frame())

# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Rowwise: 
  vector1   vector2   Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
  <list>    <list>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 <chr [5]> <dbl [5]>     1       2     6     3      4
2 <chr [5]> <dbl [5]>     3       7     9     2      4
3 <chr [5]> <dbl [5]>     5       2     8     4      0
```

This works quite well so far. However, I have a very large dataset and the `rowwise()` solution is very time consuming.
If I omit the `rowwise()` function I get an error message.
I think the error is due to the fact that I transform the vectors as a list (`as.list()`). The mutate function for the data set does not seem to be able to handle this.
The `rowwise()` function should be omitted and only the code in the `mutate` function should be changed.
Can anyone help me and provide a faster solution?

Answer (score 1):

If `vector1` has the same values (and in the same order) always like in the example we can do this in base R in a more simpler way.

```
do.call(rbind, vector2) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(vector1[[1]])

#  Reply Reshare Like Share Search
#1     1       2    6     3      4
#2     3       7    9     2      4
#3     5       2    8     4      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `mapply`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

tibble(vector1=vector1,
       vector2=vector2) %>%
  mutate(mapply(set_names, vector2, vector1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
         do.call(rbind, .) %>%
         data.frame())

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  vector1   vector2   Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
  <list>    <list>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 <chr [5]> <dbl [5]>     1       2     6     3      4
2 <chr [5]> <dbl [5]>     3       7     9     2      4
3 <chr [5]> <dbl [5]>     5       2     8     4      0
```

Here is a benchmark that compares `rowwise` against `mapply` with vectors of length 100 and shuffled labels

```r
vector1 <- replicate(sample(c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search"),
                            5,
                            replace = FALSE),
                     n = 100,
                     simplify = FALSE)

vector2 <- replicate(rnorm(5), n= 100, simplify = FALSE)


tb <- tibble(vector1 = vector1, vector2 = vector2)

microbenchmark(mapply = tb |>
                 mutate(mapply(set_names, vector2, vector1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
                        do.call(rbind, .) |>
                        data.frame()),
               rowwise = tb %>%
                 rowwise()%>%
                 mutate(vector2|> set_names(vector1)|> as.list()|> data.frame()))

+ Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  mapply  2.439877  2.487191  2.630114  2.512208  2.576073  5.990312   100
 rowwise 37.309123 37.775255 39.386047 38.193196 41.221624 44.088820   100
```